# Can mobs spawn out of paintings in minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Once my cousin had heaps of paintings in her house, and when she went in, there were mobs everywhere! She had torches,but they still spawned. Please help me coz now I'm scared of paintings!!!!

Answer (score 5):

No.

Paintings are just decoration, they do not spawn anything, in any version of Minecraft.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Painting#Pocket_and_Pi_Edition

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

In a way.

Paintings can cover secret passages by putting a block that you can walk through (sign, door, etc) and covering it with a painting.

If your cousin has a secret passage hidden under any one of those paintings, then mobs might be spawning in there and walking out through paintings.

Answer (score 0):

Painting can be placed and the blocks behind removed.
If there is a secret room of some sort behind the painting then that’s where it must be coming from. If you just place it on a wall then nothing should spawn.